# Magento2 Apis fetching product video details

Tags: magento2, api

Can anyone help me how to fetch the videos details of product in magento2 Apis

I wants display content like below screenshot in my module Api;

please find the screenshot below:

https://prnt.sc/i3ywvq

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We Can Load the Product Video Details By using the Below Code:

```
$galleryImages = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
if ($galleryImages) {
    foreach ($galleryImages as $image) {
        $imageData = $image->getData();

        // Check media type
        if (isset($imageData['media_type']) && $imageData['media_type'] == 'external-video') {
            // Your code here
        }
    }
}
```